# Can page actions be keylogged or are they securely, independently delivered

Tags: ssl, iframe, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm curious if chrome extension overlays are delivered securely and unadulterated, and whether or not someone can "listen" to internal events.

If a user were to enter a password via a chrome extension, could I guarantee that no other browser script has recorded the password? I will hash the password with 2FA so the network request is secure, but I'm curious if anyone can get the innerHtml of an `<input>` within a page action.

I'm asking because I know that generally iFrames are insecure if they're hosted in an unsecure environment where they could be "replaced" with lookalike, man in the middle, phishing palettes

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Only if you injected some element into a web page it will be a part of the web page (e.g. code in an injected `<script>`) open to any other page script.

Internal pages and scripts of an extension like page action or toolbar popup or background page and even content script environment (variables/functions) are inaccessible from the web. With a few exceptions, you can't even directly access one from another inside your extension as those are just like different tabs/windows: messaging should be used.

The only way a web page can know what happens inside your extension is to explicitly provide it with the information from your extension. You would have to explicitly send the info via DOM messaging, for example. Or via an explicit [externally_connectable](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/externally_connectable) mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe other scripts can't record the password, however you would also need to protect the input from native components like [KeyLogger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_logging), they can always get what you typed before bubbling up to browser process. So I guess a native component is also needed, it could fight with malicious keyloggers and ensure they can't get valid user input.

Comment: Yea but the OS doesn't care about HTML/CSS/JS -- Chrome is permissioned by the OS and I don't think the firewall is as important there as with browser extensions